# How can the mobile app communicate with Docker in a local machine?

Tags: android, docker, mobile, localhost

I am using Docker for the backend of my mobile app and I need to set communication between my mobile app and docker because I am running docker on my local machine because of testing the API. Postman is working well with my docker but the mobile app is not communicating with my docker as expected. If you could share any sample document or a way I would appreciate it.

**`docker-compose.yml`** :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    links:
      - game-alpha
      - main-alpha
      - main-beta
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'

  game-alpha:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.game
    container_name: game-alpha
    expose:
      - '3000'
    links:
      - redis
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./firebaseConfig.json:/root/firebaseConfig.json

  main-alpha:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.knowin
    container_name: main-alpha
    expose:
      - '8000'
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./firebaseConfig.json:/root/firebaseConfig.json
  main-beta:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.knowin
    container_name: main-beta
    expose:
      - '8000'
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./firebaseConfig.json:/root/firebaseConfig.json

  polling-alpha:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.polling
    container_name: polling-alpha
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./firebaseConfig.json:/root/firebaseConfig.json

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis 
    expose:
      - '6379'
```

**`nginx.conf`** :

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
  }

  server {
    server_name game.localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_pass http://game_nodes;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
  server {
    if ($host = game.localhost) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name game.localhost;
    return 404;
  }

  upstream game_nodes {
    # enable sticky session
    #ip_hash;
    server game-alpha:3000;
    keepalive 8;
  }

  server {
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://main_nodes;
      proxy_redirect off;

    }
  }

  server {
    if ($host = localhost) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 404;
  }

  upstream main_nodes {
    server main-alpha:8000;
    server main-beta:8000;
    keepalive 8;
  }
}
```

This is my **`NetworkModule.kt`** file from app side :

```
val NetworkModule = module {

    factory {
        Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    }

    factory {
        var URL: String = ""

        URL = "localhost"

        val authInterceptor = getAuthInterceptor(androidApplication())
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .build()


        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(get<Moshi>()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

//    Contains Retrofit Singleton Object Which Will Be Injected In Required Service
    single {
        get<Retrofit>().create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An emulated device runs on its own system and a reference to localhost addresses the device itself.
When you want to connect to your Computer on which the device is running, you need an address reserved by the device for such cases. You can read all reserved addresses for emulated devices on this site https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

```
10.0.2.2    Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)
127.0.0.1   The emulated device loopback interface
```